# Improve speed on MySQL JOIN with big data

Tags: mysql, performance, loops, join

Below are my two tables I want to fetch data from (note that these are dummy databases so don't pay attention to what data i'm pulling)

```
> DESCRIBE bigdata;

+----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| galaxy         | int(2)               | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| system         | int(3)               | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| planet         | int(2)               | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| ogame_playerid | int(11) unsigned     | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| moon           | enum('true','false') | NO   |     | false   |       |
| moonsize       | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| metal          | int(10) unsigned     | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| crystal        | int(10) unsigned     | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| planetname     | varchar(40)          | NO   |     |         |       |
+----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

also CREATE TABLE as @drew requested

```
CREATE TABLE `bigdata` (
    `galaxy` INT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `system` INT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `planet` INT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ogame_playerid` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `moon` ENUM('true','false') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false',
    `moonsize` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `metal` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `crystal` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `planetname` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`galaxy`, `system`, `planet`),
    INDEX `player_id` (`ogame_playerid`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

and the second table (note that there are more userid's)

```
SELECT * FROM smalldata WHERE userid = 1;
+----+--------+----------------+---------------------+
| id | userid | ip             | logintime           |
+----+--------+----------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      1 | 127.0.0.1      | 2016-02-25 13:50:59 |
|  2 |      1 | ::1            | 2016-02-29 23:22:18 |
|  3 |      1 | 127.0.0.1      | 2016-03-14 22:52:22 |
|  4 |      1 | 127.0.0.1      | 2016-03-22 23:27:02 |
+----+--------+----------------+---------------------+
```

My query is as below

```
SELECT smalldata.id, SUM(bigdata.planet) 
FROM smalldata LEFT JOIN bigdata ON smalldata.id = bigdata.galaxy 
WHERE smalldata.userid = 1 
GROUP BY smalldata.id;
```

My concern is that if I run such query to automatize the SELECTion on all 4 smalldata's IDs at once, it takes around 10 seconds to complete. However, if I skip the LEFT JOIN and execute 4 invidual queries on bigdata, thus "hardcoding" `WHERE galaxy = 1(or 2,3,4 respectively)`, then it takes around 0.05 second each.

I wonder why that happens. I presume that it might be that the LEFT JOIN utilizes a lot of data from columns in `bigdata` which I'm not using (which I'm not selecting) such as moon, moonsize etc. It might be perhaps that the JOIN itself is time consuming where in fact I could perform 4 selections from bigdata without actually joining those tables.

Am I misusing JOIN here?

Comment: `show create table bigdata` not `describe`

Comment: Why `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`?

Comment: `SUM(planet)` does not make logical sense.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try writing the code like this:

```
SELECT smalldata.id,
       (SELECT SUM(bigdata.planet) 
        FROM bigdata 
        WHERE smalldata.id = bigdata.galaxy 
       )
FROM smalldata
WHERE smalldata.userid = 1 ;
```

Be sure you have an index on `smalldata(userid, id)`.  Based on your description, you would seem to have the right index on `bigdata` (`galaxy` should be the first key in the index and `planet` should be in the index as well).

Comment: Unfortunatelly the execution is way longer

Comment: @Mike . . . Do you have an index on `bigdata(galaxy)` or better yet, `bigdata(galaxy, planet)`?